# Probability that two particular items are grouped in a random partition with fixed sizes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A total of $n = 3 n_1 + 2 n_2 + n_3$ distinct items labelled $1$ to $n$ are to be put into $n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ distinct boxes. To do so, the items are partitioned into groups: there are $n_1$ groups of three items, $n_2$ groups of two items, and $n_3$ groups of one item. Each group is placed in its own box. What is the probability that items $1$ and $2$ are in the same box, either as a group by themselves or in a group of three with another item?

I'm approaching this problem combinatorially.
The first roadblock I ran into is in determining the size of the sample space.
How can I count partitions of $n$ into the $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ groups of sizes $3$, $2$, and $1$ respectively?

At first, I thought of something like
$$
\binom{n}{3} \binom{n-3}{3} \binom{n-6}{3}
\cdots \binom{n - 3(n_1 + 1)}{3}
$$
to form the $n_1$ groups of three items, and them multiplying by
$$
\binom{n - 3 n_1}{2} \binom{n - 3 n_1 - 2}{2}
\cdots \binom{n - 3 n_1 - 2(n_2 + 1)}{2}
$$
to form the $n_2$ groups of two items, and so on. This gives a lot of nice cancellations, resulting in 
$$
\frac{n!}{6^{n_1} \cdot 2^{n_2} \cdot 1^{n_1}}
$$
for the number of partitions.

However, doesn't this impose a fixed ordering on the boxes, in some sense?
This process is requiring that box $1$ contain a group of three items, for instance. How can I correct for this?

Next, to count the number of partitions in which items $1$ and $2$ are in the same group, I consider two cases.

First, they form a group of two. In that case, I repeat the same process as above to count the number of ways in which $n-2$ items can be partitioned into $n_1$ groups of three, $n_2 - 1$ groups of two, and $n_3$ groups of one.

Second, they form a group of three, with some other element.
There are $n - 2$ choices for the third element they can be grouped with. Then, I repeat the same process to count the number of ways in which to partition $n-3$ items into $n_1 - 1$ groups of three, $n_2$ groups of two, and $n_3$ groups of one.

Finally, summing these two counts and dividing by the size of the sample space gives the probability.

Is this approach sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Doesn't this impose a fixed ordering on the boxes, in some sense? This process is requiring that box $1$ contain a group of three items, for instance. How can I correct for this?

It does impose a fixed order. To correct for this, we have to perform the splitting process in an extra stage.

- Partition the $n$ items into three groups: one of size $3n_1$, one of size $2n_2$, and one of size $n_3$. This can be done in
  $$
  \frac{n!}{(3n_1)! (2n_2)! n_3!}
  $$
  ways.
- Partition the $3n_1$ items into (unordered) groups of three. This can be done in
  $$
  \frac{(3n_1)!}{(3!)^{n_1} n_1!}
  =
  \frac{(3n_1)!}{6^{n_1} n_1!}
  $$
  ways.
- Partition the $2n_2$ items into (unordered) groups of two. This can be done in
  $$
  \frac{(2n_2)!}{2^{n_2} n_2!}
  $$
  ways

This gives us the number of ways in which the $n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ groups may be formed. The assignment of groups to boxes can be done in $(n_1 + n_2 + n_3)!$ ways.

Multiplying these together gives the size of the sample space.

The outlined approach for determining the number of ways in which items $1$ and $2$ are in the same box is fine.